# Cannot parse 'lastlogontimestamp' to X number of days inactive for email to managers

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am creating a script that searches AD for users that are still active but have not logged in for over 40 days and sends the manager of that user an email. I am using lastlogontimestamp and parsing it from the integer to the local time format.

However I want to expand on this. In the email, rather than have the date of the last logon, I'd like to show the X number of days since the last logon from the day the script is run.

I have hashed out how it used to work and cannot get the new version to work but feel like I am close. Apologies for anything obvious, I am a novice. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Extract from the script:

```
$users = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan (New-TimeSpan -Days 40) -Searchbase "OU=Users,OU=State,DC=Company,DC=Biz" |
         where {$_.Enabled -eq "True"} |
         Get-ADUser -Properties mail, givenname, surname, manager, lastlogontimestamp, sAMAccountName, description

#Loop through the query results
foreach ($User in $Users) {
  #Convert LastLogonDate to days since last use
  $LLTS = $User.lastLogonTimeStamp
  if ($LLTS -eq $Null) {
    $Time = [Int64]0
  } else {
    $Time = [Int64]::Parse($LLTS)
  }

  $Daysinactive = ($(Get-Date) - $([DateTime]::FromFileTime($Time)).Days)

  #Retrieve $User.Manager email address with Get-Aduser passthrough
  $Manager = Get-ADUser $User.Manager -Properties EmailAddress

  #Set dynamic variables and body of email
  $To = $Manager.EmailAddress
  $Subject = "Your employee $($User.Givenname) $($User.Surname) has been inactive for $Daysinactive ."

  #Send email
  Send-MailMessage -To $To -From $From -Subject $Subject -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml -Priority High
}
```

Additionally, I cannot seem to filter users that are over 40 days inactive, but have not ever loged on. In my firm, users are sometime created months in advance of their arrival and obviously I don't want their manager to get emails about them. Can anyone point me in the right direction for excluding them from the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lastLogonTimestamp` attribute contains the timestamp in filetime format. You can convert it directly back to a date via the static `FromFileTime()` method. Then calculate the difference between that date and the current date. The difference in days can be obtained via the `Days` property of the resulting `TimeSpan` object:

```
$lastLogon = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($User.lastLogonTimeStamp)
$Daysinactive = ((Get-Date) - $lastLogon).Days
```

However, you don't need to convert the date yourself, because the PowerShell AD cmdlets already do it for you. Simply include the `LastLogonDate` property in the property list and you'll get the last logon date as an actual date:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties mail, manager, LastLogonDate, description

foreach($User in $Users) {
  $Daysinactive = ((Get-Date) - $User.LastLogonDate).Days

  ...
}
```

The properties `GivenName`, `Surname`, and `SamAccountName` are in the default set of properties `Get-ADUser` returns, so you don't need to explicitly specify them.

Comment: Thank you Ansgar! Your reply and solution is much appreciated!

And if I could press for more, accounts that have never logged on are returning the value of 151459 days inactive as since they've never logged on, their timestamp is 1/1/1601. Is there a way to filter this?

Comment: Accounts that haven't logged on yet have an empty `LastLogonDate` property, so you could filter for accounts with a non-empty property: `... | ? { $_.LastLogonDate }`.